# Can not use CSS for my navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to modify my navigation bar with CSS, but whatever I add into the CSS does not change on the page.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<title>Sketch</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
</div>

</body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.nav{
width:100%;
height:30px;
text-align:center;
background:#f1f1f1;
}
```

Comment: He's obviously new to web programming. I'm pretty sure everyone has made obvious mistakes when they started for there first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done it wrong, `.nav` should be `#nav`

Comment: No problem, just remember next time to double check Ur CSS.

Answer (score 3):

it should be `#nav` and not `.nav`

Answer (score 2):

You have used an ID (#) for your nav div.

Either change it to a class or change your CSS to

```
#nav{
width:100%; <-- BTW not required, all divs are 100% width by default
height:30px;
text-align:center;
background:#f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're style is set to the class `.net` no the id `#nav`, this should match you node:

```
#nav{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#f1f1f1;
}
```